# Inside our Power App customized form, the SharePoint Lookup field which referecne a list that contain 2 million records is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, list-view-threshold

I have a Parent SharePoint online list which contain over 2 million++ records, as follow:-

[image]

and inside another list (Child list) i have a lookup field which reference the above parent list, as follow:-

[image]

and inside the Parent list i added the Title as an index column, as follow:-

[image]

now when i customized the Child list's Create/Edit form using Power App, i will get these warning + the lookup field on runtime will be disabled:-

[image]

Any advice ? per my knowledge that defining the correct Index on the Parent list should allow us to reference the list using Lookup field, even if the list has more than 5,000 records... but seems this is not working in my case? am i missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Power Apps is not SharePoint. It's a separate service. It can connect to SharePoint as a datasource though. As a result, when creating SharePoint forms using Power Apps, we end up with a lot more restricted than using SharePoint alone.

- All SharePoint restrictions apply
- Power Apps have a lot of restrictions of their own. For example, You can't *easily* work with arrays containing more than 2000 items.

As a result, I would not even try forcing your Power Apps to somehow work with a list containing over a million items.

However, feel free to try these workarounds. Spoiler alert: then won't work very well.

**Workaround #1: Use Starts with for searching**

- Index a SharePoint search field that you will use for searching.
- In Power App create a new text box field that you will use for searching.
- Create a gallery that will display filtered items.
- The gallery will connect to the SharePoint Lookup list and filter items using **Starts with** condition. Or **equals** condition. None other filtering methods like **contains** will work.

So, users will search for an item they want to select, then click on it in the gallery, then it's your responsibility to grab the value from the gallery and somehow save it later.

**Workaround #2. Load SharePoint List into memory**

This method will not work with such a large list like yours. But perhaps, you can filter it down so that you are left with no more than 10K items.

- [Read TOMASZ POSZYTEK's "OVERCOME 2000 ITEMS LIMIT USING POWER APPS COLLECT FUNCTION" article](https://poszytek.eu/en/microsoft-en/office-365-en/powerapps-en/overcome-2000-items-limit-using-power-apps-collect-function/)
- Create custom ID field. You have to do it because the OOB ID field has restrictions in Power Apps.
- Calculate number of iterations like so:

```
Set(
    firstRecord,
    First('Large List')
);
Set(
    lastRecord,
    First(
        Sort(
            'Large List',
            ID,
            Descending
        )
    )
);
Set(
    iterationsNo,
    RoundUp(
        (lastRecord.ID - firstRecord.ID) / 500,
        0
    )
);
Collect(iterations, Sequence(iterationsNo,0));
```

- Create collection, where each item is a number of an iteration:

```
ForAll(
    iterations,
    With(
        {
            prevThreshold: Value(Value) * 500,
            nextThreshold: (Value(Value) + 1) * 500
        },
        If(
            lastRecord.ID > Value,
            Collect(
                LargeListSP,
                Filter(
                    'Large List',
                    ID_val > prevThreshold && ID_val <= nextThreshold
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I tried this approach on a list with 100K items and it was *super* slow. I think, I had to wait for at least 1-2 minutes before I downloaded that many items in memory. Then I tried opening this app from a mobile device and the speed was 10 times slower. Loading even 10K items from Samsung S9 took ages.

**Summary**

Power Apps + SharePoint is not a good combinations when dealing with large lists. Find a way to never load more than 500-2000 items in your Power app. If you do need large volumes of data then you probably need different technologies:

- SQL Azure
- Azure Cosmos DB
- Azure Services
- SPFx
- etc.

Comment: i do not agree with you.. Power app gallery are able to load any number of SharePoint items, even the 2 Million items. but it will load them in patches as you scroll down or left you can reach all items.. so i am can use SharePoint and Power Apps on large lists,, the only issue i am facing is with the lookup fields. now i found a workaround of storing the Parent ID as a Single Line of text instead of using lookups.... but i am asking to see other ideas for managing the lookup between large lists.. but for me SharePoint and Power Apps are working perfectly on these large lists.

Comment: why you want to show 2Million items on the screen. even when i write pure .NET web application which connect to SQL server.. i do the paginating on the server.. so if you click on Next the next batch on items will be shown.. and the Power app galleries do have a pagination... when you the end of a scrolling the gallery will automatically fetch the next patch of 100 items till you get all the 2 Millions items.. try it at your end...

Comment: so i do not see that SharePoint & PowerApps do not suites large lists,, but the idea is to have enough experience in both technologies to be able to work with large lists

Comment: You are right about the galleries. I forgot they support paginations. But then again, how does it help you work with a list of 2m items? How are you going to force the gallery to show you one millionth's item, for example? Are you going to scroll the gallery for 6 hours to get there?

Comment: "why you want to show 2Million items on the screen". Sorry, but I never said I want 2 million items on the screen. In my answer I explain that you have to use Begins with and Equals conditions to filter a small portion of your datasource.

Comment: no i do not need to show all the one million items.. even if i am working with .NET & SQL server.. but at the end the user can get as much data as he/she wants with galleries.. this is the concept of pagination in web application,, this is not something unique in SharePoint and Power apps... even this forum has a pagination

Comment: "no i do not need to show all the one million items". John, I didn't say you wanted to show million items. Please, re-read what I said. I asked you this question: "How are you going to force the gallery to show you one millionth's item, for example?" I am really confused why you are so defensive and what you don't agree with? The only points you don't agree with are the ones I actually never said. So I'm really confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131022/discussion-between-denis-molodtsov-and-john-gu).